# postgresql query problem got rows as many as the result length

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query where I use some functions like JSON_AGG.
I named it `durationContract` in the JSON_AGG where I get price and duration. I have 1 entry there. The problem is I got 4x the entries because I have 4 rows. If I have 5 rows I get 5x the same entry in JSON_AGG, also in array_agg.

code

```sql
SELECT
      ca.id,
      ca.name,
      ca.image,

      json_agg(json_build_object(
        'fuel', ca.fuel,
        'engine', ca.engine,
        'type', ca.type
      )) AS details,

      ARRAY_AGG(ci.image) as images,

      json_agg(json_build_object(
        'price', cc.price,
        'duration', cc.duration
      )) AS durationContract,

      json_agg(json_build_object(
        'price', ck.price,
        'duration', ck.duration
      )) AS km

FROM car_abo ca

INNER JOIN car_images ci
ON ci.car_id = ca.id

INNER JOIN car_contract cc
ON cc.car_id = ca.id

INNER JOIN car_km ck
ON ck.car_id = ca.id

GROUP BY 
      ca.id
```

What I am doing wrong?

€:

If I edit this with GROUP BY then it works but then it does not group by id and I have 4x the same row like 16x rows

```
ca.id,
ca.name,
ca.image,
ci.id,
ck.id,
cc.id
```

Comment: Image you closed your eyes and attempted to describe this problem. It would be difficult because you cannot see any data. The same is true of someone attempting to answer your question, we need to "see" the data too. Ideally you would supply not just your query results, but some data **for each table** so we can replicate (and then solve) your problem. You will get better answers, and faster answers, if you provide **sample data** (per table) and the **expected result** (using only the sample data).

Comment: My **guess** is that you need to do the aggregation as a subquery, probably here: `INNER JOIN (select ... from car_km GROUP BY ...) ck ON ck.car_id = ca.id` i.e. aggregate the JSON from the table that stores the JSON, do this before joining the other tables. Remember that each join will MULTIPLY rows if there is a "many-to-one" relationship in the data.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**; also adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful. Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues.